# AWS Rekognition with Lambda – what is the correct ARN ressource name for the policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

I want to use the Amazon Lambda blueprint (Python) for S3/Rekognition. I made sure all my ressources are in eu-west-1 which is one of the three regions where Rekognition is available.

While trying to add an inline policy to the role I use and get stuck at the ARN field. I tried the S3 ARN as well as the ARN of the Lambda function itself to no avail.

I always get this error:

> Resource field is not valid. You must enter a valid ARN

[image]

What is the correct ARN that I have to enter?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Rather than adding an inline policy I added the required policies as «Managed Policies»:

[image]